# Android Image corrupted

Tags: c#, android, image, imageview

My application downloads a number of objects from a server.

The communication between mobile and server uses the Eneter Messaging Framework.
Every object has an image and a number of other primitive values.
My server is written in C#. I retrieve the image from the database as a byte array,
convert it to an `Icon`, convert that to a byte array and then send it back to the mobile.

I'm trying to display it on an ImageView gives me this result :

[image]

Why do my images appear as corrupt?

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help you without either the server or the client side code...

Comment: Why convert to icon?  Send the raw data and convert in Android.

Comment: The image size is at least 25 kB, thats why i try to compress them before sending them back